# Why can we find roots of trigonometric equations using the unit circle?

Tags: trigonometry, roots, circles

I always get a bit confused in finding all the roots in the given domain of a trigonometric equation.

Suppose this example from the book "*Trigonometry by I.M.Gelfand*":

> Find all solutions of $\sin x =1/2$ for $0<x<2\pi$

[image: solution]

I do not understand how both are acceptable solutions, would the angle on the top left quadrant not correspond to $-\frac{1}{2}$?

As far as I know the $\arcsin$ function is not even either so it does not make sense how this is an acceptable answer for me, what is the reasoning behind this? 
And is this the case for all the principle trigonometric functions?

Comment: The sine function of an angle is the $y$-coordinate of the point with that angle on the unit circle. The point on the left has the same $y$-coordinate as the point on the right: $1/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an interpretation question, I don't need to see work.

In the 1st quadrant, the pertinent (x,y) coordinate is

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

The sine function is associated with the $y$ coordinate, so in the first quadrant, the sine is

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

In the 2nd quadrant, the pertinent (x,y) coordinate is

$$\left(\frac{-\sqrt{3}}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Since the sine function is always associated with the $y$ coordinate, whatever that coordinate happens to be, in the second quadrant, the sine is still

$$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

When looking at sines you're looking at the height (projection on the y axis of the radius vector) of the triangle formed by the radius and the x axis. This height on the first and second quadrant is clearly positive.

That means that all sines on the upper half of the xy plane are positive.

For cosines you're looking at the length (projection on the x axis), so obviously cosines are positive on the first and fourth quadrant, but negative everywhere else.

Comment: That is of course assuming the radius is 1. Otherwise you'd have that the projections are $r\cos(\theta)$ and $r\sin(\theta)$

Comment: From the title, it *is* "the unit circle"...

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. Just wanted to make it clearer for the op.